# What does "Please define $JAVANLP_HOME where your CoreNLP Java checkout is" means?

Tags: java, python, stanford-nlp

[corenlp.client](https://i.stack.imgur.com/12ADv.png)

i want use python-stanford-corenlp, but i didn't install java tool and jdk, so what i'm gonna do? How do i define a JAVANLP_HOME? Appreciate it!!!!

Comment: It is environment variable. The way how to set it depend on your OS.

Comment: I am pretty sure that there must be a tutorial somewhere, outlining the required steps ...

Comment: my OS is ubuntu, and i downloaded the corenlp jars. Does the JAVANLP_HOME point the path of corenlp jars???